# Callback javascript function inside other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions:

```
function changeImage(imgName)
{
image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
image.src = imgName;
}

function changeSize()
{
document.getElementById('imgDisp').setAttribute("datamask","../files/test/2.png");
}
```

They are both called with an "onclick" event:

```
 <img id="imgTemp" onclick="changeImage('../files/templates/blank/<? echo($one['id'])?>.jpg');changeSize();"
```

What I want is so that *changeSize* is called again after *changeImage* is executed. I was advised to use callback but most examples I have seen deal with variable callback inside a function and not with two functions.

Edit: The function change size should put a mask on the image, giving the "datamask" as a parameter to another function in another .js file. The image gets the right "datamask" parameter, but the mask is not applied.

Comment: Simply call `changeSize()` in `changeImage` function

Comment: It is actualy called right after changeImage is executed. I don't get what's wrong with this .. `:/`

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J424R/1/

Comment: The above code _should_ work, assuming that you actually close the `img` tag and you change its `id` to `imgDisp`. Provide more information about the behaviour you expect and you get.

Comment: @blgt I've added an explanation as the what to expect from the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `changeSize()` inside `changeImage()` instead:

```
function changeImage(imgName)
{
image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
image.src = imgName;
changeSize();
}
```

then you can remove `changeSize();` from your `onclick` function:

```
<img id="imgTemp" onclick="changeImage('../files/templates/blank/<? echo($one['id'])?>.jpg');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImage(imgName)
{
image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
image.src = imgName;
changeSize();
}

function changeSize()
{
document.getElementById('imgDisp').setAttribute("datamask","../files/test/2.png");
} 


<img id="imgTemp" onclick="changeImage('../files/templates/blank/<? echo($one['id'])?>.jpg');changeSize();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `changeSize()` to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, but I would place the url you echo out in the html attribute in a data attribute.
This would be a bit more stable and clean.
http://jsbin.com/gijiketi/1/edit?html,js